# Issue with Folder or File 'root' permission in linux

Tags: java, linux, file-io

I am creating folder/file in linux using jdk 1.4 (mkdir). I am running this code from my application using test user(limited permission). But the folder/file is creating with root permission. I need to delete these files and folders manually at later time. When i try to delete the folder/file i got access denied. The JDK is installed in root.

How can i create the folder/file with different user permission (non root) in **java 1.4**?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files will be created with the owner of whatever your VM runs as. If you want to run as  a different user, [`su - <userid>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) is your friend.

You can eg. use the `--command` param to `mkdir` your directory.

Cheers,

Comment: If VM runs as root to create the dir, it should be able to delete well?

Comment: @Anders: Is there any way to do in java 1.4?

Comment: @KingsIndian : I am deleting it manually - meaning from different user

Comment: @sudha you miss showing us exactly how you create the directory/file, but in *any* java version you can do it with [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your program as root user? in that case it will create files also as root user, so either run your program also as test user, or use `sudo -u <username> mkdir <dirname>`.